# COUNTIFS for dates within last 12 months

Tags: excel

I'm trying to count the number of dates in a range that fall within the last 12 months. The formula I have now counts YTD. Anyone know how i can adjust the formula to count the last 12 months?

```
=COUNTIFS(O19:O500,"*",L19:L500,B7,P19:P500,">43831")
```

Comment: change `">43831"` to something like `">" & Today()-365`

Comment: or `">" & edate(today(),-12)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks! Both work perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following formulas work:

```
=COUNTIFS(O19:O500,"*",L19:L500,B7,P19:P500,">" & Today()-365))

=COUNTIFS(O19:O500,"*",L19:L500,B7,P19:P500,">" & edate(today(),-12))
```